# can I get unique watch time using sql

Tags: sql

Here is my sample input data.

```
user_id   video_id   watch_start_min    watch_end_min
-----------------------------------------------------
1           v1            0                5
1           v1            7               10
1           v1            3                4
2           v2            5                8
2           v2            6                8
2           v2            1                2
```

user_id watch video v1 from 0th to 5th min first and skip from 7th min to 10th min after that. he again come back and watch 3rd min to 4th min. So his unique watch time is 5 min from first row + 3 from second row + 0 from 3rd row since it is already covered in first row

Expected output

```
user_id     video_id    unique_watch_time
-----------------------------------------
1             v1            8       
2             v2            4
```

(explanation: 3 from 4th row +0 from 5th row since it is covered in 4th row + 1 from last row)

I can achieve this using python but I am not sure if this can be done through sql or not.

Thanks for help and sorry if formatting does not look good.

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to SO. What is the DBMS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes you're using an RDBMS that allows the usage of common table expressions and windowing functions. The idea is to find watch-periods that are in the same group. Essentially, the idea is to define groups such that the `watch_start` time of rows fall within the same "group".

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, COALESCE(CASE WHEN watch_start BETWEEN lag_ws AND lag_we THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 1) AS gp
    FROM
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id, video_id ORDER BY watch_start) AS seq,
              LAG(watch_start, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id, video_id ORDER BY watch_start) AS lag_ws,
              LAG(watch_end, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id, video_id ORDER BY watch_start) AS lag_we
    FROM vids
    ) a1                                        
)

SELECT person_id, video_id, SUM(max_we - min_ws) AS watch_time
FROM
(
    SELECT person_id, video_id, MIN(watch_start) AS min_ws, MAX(watch_end) AS max_we
    FROM
    (
    SELECT person_id, video_id, watch_start, watch_end,
    SUM(gp) OVER(PARTITION BY person_id, video_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grps
    FROM cte
    ) a2
    GROUP BY person_id, video_id, a2.grps
) a3
GROUP BY person_id, video_id
```

OUTPUT:

```
person_id    video_id   watch_time
    1            v1              8    
    2            v2              4
```

Comment: There is an error on the query. For example, if a video watched from 0 to 10 for v1. The result is incorrect.

Comment: Golly, you're right. I'm going to try using a recursive approach to this. Thanks!

Comment: After spending whole lot amount of time, I feel python should be easier than working hard on sql front.